# Use Replace Method In Linq-Sql Query

Tags: c#, regex, linq-to-sql

I used RegEx to remove HTML TAGS within LINQ-SQL query but the following error has thrown:

> Method `'System.String Replace(System.String, System.String, System.String)'` is not supported for execution as SQL.

```
Help helpDBSession = new Help();
          IEnumerable<Article> articles = null;
          if (lang.ToLower() == "en")
          {
              articles = helpDBSession.Articles.Where(artilce =>  artilce.NameEn.Contains(searchPattern) ||
                       System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(artilce.ContentEn, "<(.|\n)*?>",String.Empty).Contains(searchPattern));
          }
          else
          {
              articles = helpDBSession.Articles.Where(artilce => artilce.NameAr.Contains(searchPattern) ||

                  System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(artilce.ContentAr, "<(.|\n)*?>", String.Empty).Contains(searchPattern));
          }
          if (articles != null && articles.Count() > 0)
          {
              return articles.ToList();
          }
```

Comment: It would help if you provided the actual linq code.

Comment: The `String.Replace` function only takes 2 parameters and returns a `string`. Can you show us your code?

Comment: @Matt - good point. I assumed it was a static function of String, but looks like it's a local function.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb737939.aspx#strcont it translates to a `like` statement so no RegExp. You could filter on client or use CLR integration of M$ SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

Two things wrong here:

1. You are parsing HTML with a RegEx. You should use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse out HTML, not rely on RegEx. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) for reasons why.
2. You are treating Linq2Sql as if SQL is not around - when using `Replace`, it tries to pass it through to SQL Server - this of course fails, as SQL does not have this function. This would fail anyway, as there is no overload to `string.Replace` that takes three strings.

You did not explain what exactly you need to achieve, but if you need to store some HTML in SQL, I suggest you parse it with the agility pack and use that for cleaning out the tags, then save the result to SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message I'm assuming LINQ to SQL can not translate the RegEx section of the LINQ statements because SQLServer does not support RegEx.

You will have to:

- Get articles from the database with on the "Contains" section of your where statement.
- Convert the on the results to a list.
- Apply your regular expression to a where on the list.

For example:

```
Help helpDBSession = new Help();

IEnumerable<Article> articles = null;

if (lang.ToLower() == "en")
{
    articles = helpDBSession.Articles.Where(
                   artilce =>  artilce.NameEn.Contains(searchPattern)
    )
}
else
{
    articles = helpDBSession.Articles.Where(
                   artilce => artilce.NameAr.Contains(searchPattern)
    )
}

if (articles != null && articles.Count() > 0)
{
    if (lang.ToLower() == "en")
    {
        return articles.ToList().Where(
            artilce => System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(
                artilce.ContentEn, 
                "<(.|\n)*?>",String.Empty).Contains(searchPattern)
            )
        );
    }
    else
    {
        return articles.ToList().Where(
            artilce => System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(
                artilce.ContentAr, 
                "<(.|\n)*?>",String.Empty).Contains(searchPattern)
            )
        );
     }
}
```